# Can two distinct $L^2$ functions have the same $L^2$ derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Take $f' = g' \in L^2$ for $f, g \in L^2 (\mathbb R)$. It seems that taking the Fourier transform gives $f = g$ except on a set of measure zero (using the fact that $\hat{f'}(x) = ix \hat f(x)$) - does this make sense? I think it does because you can't translate a function up and maintain its $L^2$ integrability, but I was a bit confused because it seems unintuitive.

Comment: If $f=\chi_{(0,1)}$ and $g=\chi_{(0,2)}$ you get a counterexample

Comment: But you are right, if $f$ is in $L^2$ then $f+c$ can't be in $L^2$ because it dos not vanish at Infinity

Comment: Simple enough! What is wrong with the reasoning that implies $f =g$ then? Because we get $\hat f = \hat g$, so the inverse Fourier transforms must agree too.

Comment: Your argument not proves that $f=g$ but that   $\hat{f}=\hat{g}$

Comment: Actually, do the functions you cite have the same weak derivative? Applied to the derivative of the test function $\phi$, don't we get $\phi(2)-\phi(0)$ and $\phi(1) -\phi(0)$?

Comment: Isn't the Fourier transform one to one in $L^2$?

Comment: These funcions are in $L^1$ too. And in $L^1$ we have unicity if $\hat{f}\in L^1$ too, otherwise you cant apply the inverse fourier transform

Comment: I think Fourier transform gives an isometry of $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Hmmm.... You're right... I don't understand where does the problem comes from

Comment: Your argument seems fine. You could also see it by noting that if $f'=g'$ then $f$ and $g$ can only differ by a constant. But this constant must be $0$, since they are both square integrable.

Comment: @Marcos the derivatives of your functions are not in $L^2$